# Reason behind a property in conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

If $E[X|Y=y]=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y+1}{\mu+1}f_{X|Y}(x|y+1)dx$, then why is $E[X|Y=y]=\frac{y+1}{\mu+1}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{y}{\mu+1}$ since we are looking for $E[X|Y=y]$ and not $E[X|Y=y+1]$? I came across this in the [answer key](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn11_sol.pdf) of part ii, b, problem 2 of this MIT OCW [problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn11.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have shown that $xf_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{y+1}{\mu+1}f_{X|Y}(x|y+1)$, thus 
$$
E[X|Y=y]=\int xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx=\int \frac{y+1}{\mu+1}f_{X|Y}(x|y+1)dx= \frac{y+1}{\mu+1}\int f_{X|Y}(x|y+1)dx=\frac{y+1}{\mu+1}\times1.
$$
As $\frac{y+1}{\mu+1}$ does not depend on $x$, thus you just take an integration over a density function - that equals $1$.